# script to search address on google maps

Tags: java, regex, r, google-maps, web-scraping

I have names of 1100 hospitals from NY region. I need to find the address of these hospitals from google. I am looking for some script which I can use to supply all these hospital name and it could return me with an address. The script could return a simple google search result.
Input format:

```
Hospital Name
Center for Ambulatory Surgery
Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc
```

Desired output format:

```
Hospital Name   Hospital Address
Center for Ambulatory Surgery   3112 Sheridan Dr, Amherst, NY 14226
Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc 490 Delaware Ave, Buffalo, NY 14202
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code, or researching the proper APIs? There is a [fairly generous free usage limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) for Google's API.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests), but the results may be not very accurate: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JogeyV?editors=101

```
  var NY_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.828624, -73.898605);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: NY_latlng,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var hospitals = [];
  var hospitals_names = ["Center for Ambulatory Surgery","Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc"];//insert your full list here

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  hospitals_names.forEach( function(name ){

    service.textSearch(
                        {
                         query: name, 
                         location: NY_latlng,
                         radius: 50000, //in meter
                        },function(results,status){

                  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
                    var hospital= { name: name, addresses: []};
                    $('#address-list').append("<h2>"+name+"</h2><ul></ul>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                      hospital.addresses.push( results[i].formatted_address );

                        $('#address-list > ul').append("<li>"+results[i].formatted_address);
                    }
                    hospitals.push( hospital );

                  }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in R with the `ggmap` package, though perhaps not reliably enough to produce the results you want.  For instance this attempt to geocode fails:

```
geocode("Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc")

Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc"
```

So to illustrate a solution, I appended " NY" to the Google searches:

```
library(ggmap)
hospital_names <- c("Center for Ambulatory Surgery", "Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc")
address_vec <- lapply(hospital_names, function(x) revgeocode(as.numeric(geocode(paste(x,", NY")))))
result <- data.frame(name = hospital_names, address = unlist(address_vec))
```

Result:

```
result
                           name                                      address
1 Center for Ambulatory Surgery   426 Union Road, West Seneca, NY 14224, USA
2   Genetic Diagnostic Labs Inc City Hall Park Path, New York, NY 10007, USA
```

But these are not the addresses you specified - you may need to refine your inputs.

Comment: See also `dismo::geocode`, which takes a vector of place names.